# EF CORE UPDATE column adding value to it

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-core-3.0

How do I convert this SQL command below into C# EF CORE?

```
UPDATE table
   SET vlr = vlr + 100
 WHERE id = 1
```

Note: The current value in the "vlr" column is 1000.

With this code below:

```
var reg = await _context.Table.FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == 1);

reg.Vlr = reg.Vlr + 100;

Or

reg.Vlr += 100;
```

Results in SQL this SQL Command:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [table] SET [vlr] = @p0
WHERE [id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;',N'
@p0 decimal(5,2),@p1 int',@p0=1100,@p1=1
```

I Need a result like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [table] SET [vlr] = [vlr] + @p0
WHERE [id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;',N'
@p0 decimal(5,2),@p1 int',@p0=100,@p1=1
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Why do you care which place does the sum? Is it because of concurrent access?

Comment: If it is the case I think you need to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency or use a stored procedure or raw sql for this

Comment: Correct Caius Jard, for every operation that the system processes I have to add the value of that operation to that column in order to have a total value. A Sum does not apply in this scenario. Thankful.

Comment: I solved the problem with RAW Command, I just wanted to know if there was a way to execute this UPDATE directly by EF, and not by a SQL RAW command.